# Pivot table in access

Tags: ms-access, pivot-table

HI I am a new bee to access...
HI I have a table as [image]

It store the Medical Type id for particular study id

the look up for medical type is as

[image]

Now I have another look up table for Disease as

[image]

Now I want the data in pivot for grouped by study id and column as Medical_Type names  and corresponding disease name with Yes and No as there value 
as
[image]

How can I achieve this ...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can

1.) left-join the two lower tables from the first one (in view builder, add all three tables, create a link between the linking columns and double-click the created link to select which table defines the population),

2.) create a crosstab

3.) set study_id as row

4.) set medical_type as column

5.) instead of y/n you can set "count(medical_type)" as value.

If you insist on y/n, you can create a new view, using your crosstab as input and define 'iif(count>0,"Y","N")'

I hope this is what you wanted.

Regards

Comment: I have tries this.. the problem with this is that it combines up study id

Comment: I used the code                      <br>    SELECT  PatientRelatesMedicalHistory.Study_Id, 
  mstMedicalType.Medical_Type, 
  mstMedicalDetails.Text_Data
  
FROM (PatientRelatesMedicalHistory 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN mstMedicalDetails
on mstMedicalDetails.Value_Data=cstr(PatientRelatesMedicalHistory.Disease_Id))

LEFT OUTER JOIN mstMedicalType
ON mstMedicalType.ID = cint(PatientRelatesMedicalHistory.Medical_Type_Id);

Comment: that doesn't look like you use a crosstab query. Else you would have a groupBy somewhere. I guess you want to group by study_id (row) and medical_type (column).

Comment: before pivoting table I want the table in the format like Study id/Column Name/(option = Yes/NO) once I get data as this form then I will apply pivot for cross tab.. but above query is not returning data in the desired format