# Group records and show each records value in one row

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am having trouble using group by query in MS-access.
I am having table structure as below.

```
Number    Date              Marks
1         2011/3/25           20 
1         2012/3/21           50    
1         2013/3/22           22
1         2014/3/25           56
```

I want to show data like below

```
Number      march-2011    march-2012    march-2013   
 1          20            50            22
```

Could anyone please help me with this. how can i do this in ms-access using query . I am new to ms-access.

Comment: Looks like you tried (did you?) to create a pivot table. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591221/pivot-table-in-access) about the same subject might provide some insights, as might tutorials like [this](http://dotnet.tech.ubc.ca/CourseWiki/index.php?title=Access_2010_PivotTable) or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZgerpTHzQes).

Comment: @ GolezTrol :is it even possible using a query?

Comment: I'm not sure. It's a pretty advanced subject, and even in 'big' databases like Oracle and MySQL it's a tough job.

Answer (score 0):

This query simply requires conditional aggregation:

```
select number,
       sum(iif(year(date) = 2011 and month(date) = 3, Marks, 0)) as March2011,
       sum(iif(year(date) = 2012 and month(date) = 3, Marks, 0)) as March2012,
       sum(iif(year(date) = 2013 and month(date) = 3, Marks, 0)) as March2013
from table
group by number;
```